# JasperReport center and right align not exporting to PDF

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I'm using JasperSoft Studio and compiling the project with JasperReport 5.5.

In the studio center and right aligned text fields build and preview fine.
However, when I use the JasperReport  exportReportToPDF() method in the application, all text is left aligned.

the JRXML uses the textAlignment attribute.

```
<textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{weekday}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Does anyone know anything about this issue? Perhaps the attribute is not right for PDF?

**EDIT**

Are report Styles suported in JasperReports version 5.5.
JasperSoft Studio crashes when I try to use a report Style(using JasperReport version 5.5 in the workspace).

The alignment issue seems to be inheritance related. The subreport renders text aligned properly (right, or center) when used on its own, but when rendered in the main report the alignment is lost.

Comment: Do you have some styles (internal or external)? Are you using some font? It is better to post the small sample (*jrxml* file) to reproduce your problem and a screenshot of a wrong result

Comment: Did you find solution for that? I am having same issue now with 6.3.1 version of jaspersoft studio.